# Is Nginx's PAM module "safe"?

Tags: nginx, security, pam

**Background:**
I would like to implement HTTP auth for a section of a website hosted with Nginx, but allow users to use the same password they use for samba/shell login, similar to what is possible with Windows Authentication on IIS.

**Question:**
[ngx_http_auth_pam_module](https://github.com/sto/ngx_http_auth_pam_module) seems to do what I want, but this line in the readme scares me:

> you need to let the web server user to read the /etc/shadow file

I understand that shadow holds password hashes rather than passwords, but that still seems like a "Bad Thing" to expose to the www-data group, given that these hashes and the associated user names are potentially exposed to the web.

*Is this a valid fear, or am I just being paranoid?*

**Aside:**
With a little bit of digging, it seems like PAM auth should be doable without being able to access shadow, so I'm not sure why the plugin is implemented this way...